# Heap corruption while free memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have function that allocates memory for `char* c` variable and later frees it. Got error while debug:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Error!

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#95) at 0x0130BE00.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

What I do wrong?

```
void logHex(char* value, int len, int level)
{
    if (LogHnd)
    {
        char* c = (char*)calloc(len * 3, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            sprintf(c, "%s%02X ",c,value[i]);
        }
        LogHnd(c, level);
        free(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(c, "%s%02X ",c,value[i]);` - Why do you write `c` as a string (`%s`) into itself ?

Comment: You need to allocate an extra character for the null terminator

Comment: @wohlstad Because he is trying to append to `c`

Comment: A correct solution using `sprintf` uses a temporary string `char t[4]; sprintf(t, "%02X ", value[i]); strcat(c, t);` Assuming 0 <= value[i] <= 255. A more efficient version would calculate the offset and use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`.

Comment: @john Yes, I'm trying to append. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @Alan Birtles Adding extra char solves the problem.

Comment: @vico Apparently it's not allowed (see answer below). Even if allowed it would be inefficient. Another possible error is a negative value in your array.

Comment: @vico No format arguments might overlap with the destination buffer, so you can't use `c` as both the destination and the source for a `%s` format specifier.

Comment: And I really recommend you invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ properly. Any time you must use C-style casting (like you do for the result of `calloc`) should be taken as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: char* calloc, sprintf  and free Your code is "C" not "C++". In C++ I'd expect things like std::string, std::make_unique, std::format and std::cout

Comment: @john What do you mean negative value in array?

Comment: @vico Your array is of `char`, `char` maybe (and usually is) a signed type. So the values in your array go from -128 to 127. But I'm guessing you want to print values from 0 to 255. So negative values are going to print incorrectly. To fix this you should cast to `unsigned char`, i.e. `(unsigned char)value[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same pointer as both source and destination in `sprintf` leads to *undefined behavior*.

Use `std::string` for all your string needs in C++, and then you can use the plain `+` operator to append strings.

To format strings use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), [the format library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) or [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (if your compiler is new enough).

---

Using `std::ostringstream` it could be something like this:

```
std::string c;

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    c += (std::ostringstream{} << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned>(value[i])).str();
}
```

Using `std::format` it could be something like:

```
std::string c;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    c += std::format("{:02x}", static_cast<unsigned>(value[i]));
}
```

With the format library it would be the same, but with the `fmt` namespace instead of `std`.

Note that I cast the `char` value in `value[i]` to an `unsigned` integer, because it's implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. If `char` is signed, then values above `0x7f` would be considered negative, and lead to sign extension which would add a lot of leading `f` hexadecimal digits to the value.